# Javascript CommonJS - where's the module?

Tags: javascript, module, commonjs

So I'm using modules in a personal project for the usual reasons (namespace protection and dependency handling (require) and public API definition (exports)). I wrote my own require() method and am using the standard module pattern -- i.e.:

```
var myModule = (function() {
   var exports = {};

   function sayHello() {
      return "hi";
   }
   exports.sayHello = sayHello;

   return exports;
})();
```

So I want to standardize my stuff on CommonJS standard (this is for server-side JS and my question is *not* about CommonJS versus other module standards). Everything I read about CommonJS says that a module looks like this

```
function sayHello() {
   return "hi";
}
exports.sayHello = sayHello
```

And that's it! But that's not a module. Something must be wrapping this *as an actual module!* I have not found a single site discussing CommonJS modules that says how this gets turned into an actual module. Am I missing something that everybody else seems to know?

So my questions are:

What is doing the wrapping? -- i.e., what turns it into an actual module? A library of some sort, I assume.

What does this final, wrapped, CommonJS module look like? I want to write an implementation of the CommonJS standard, but can't find any documentation of what that final module is supposed to look like.

Is the "exports" variable in the global scope? If not, what is providing the exports object to the module if it's not being explicitly declared in the body of the module code? And who's doing it - the caller of the module?

Dang. It seemed simple when I wrote it myself. Now it seems like magic. A link to some comprehensive documentation would be great.

NOTE: I know *very little* about node.js and don't intend to use it in this project, so if you answer, *please don't answer in node.js-speak.*

Comment: "What is doing the wrapping?" — It depends on the host environment. Browser implementations will be different to Node.js implementations which will be different to WSH implementations and so on.

Comment: *I wrote my own require() method* - How did you do that? what does it do? and why are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: NodeJS handles CommonJS implicitly for you. Browser environments *won't* do this, and to use CommonJS patterns in them, you will need a JavaScript bundler such as Browserify or Webpack (at least until ES6 lands in all major browsers)

Comment: @Amit - My question is _what is this wheel?_  I wrote what i needed at the time -- namely a way to manage modules. Now i want to understand the internals of CommonJS so that i can possibly use the _wheel_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is doing the wrapping?

Node is. It can access the filesystem, so it caches the code from all the files that have been required, and delivers it to the namespaces that required it.

> What does this final, wrapped, CommonJS module look like?

The actual code where modules are wrapped will probably be in `module.js`, which is a core file in the `lib` folder of Node's installation.

> Is the "exports" variable in the global scope?

The `exports` is a property of the `module` object within a file. The `module` is the global scope inside that file. The `exports` property is what is returned by the module to the code that requires it.

The key thing to remember is that the CommonJS ethos is built-in to Node's core modular code. There is no magical implementation in the V8 which dictates that `module.exports` is a 'thing'. This may all change when implementing ES6 modules becomes the norm.

You might find it useful reading [this](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/).

You may find it even more useful to give up on your quest to re-write `require()`. :-)

Comment: Thanks shennan. Too late to give up on my quest to rewrite require() -- it's already done! It was actually necessary because I'm using Nashorn, so to mimic what Node (etc) does, I needed to deal with dependency management.

Comment: that link is great BTW. Super useful.

Comment: @misterblinky in that case, https://avatar-js.java.net/ . I haven't attempted to use it. I just know it's a thing. Also, http://nodyn.io/

Answer (score 0):

I hope that node.js documentation can answer all of your questions.

So, according to the [node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#the-module-wrapper)

Before a module's code is executed, Node.js will wrap it with a function wrapper that looks like the following:

```js
(function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  // Module code actually lives in here
});
```

By doing this, Node.js achieves a few things:

- It keeps top-level variables (defined with `var`, `const` or `let`) scoped to the module rather than the global object.
- It helps to provide some global-looking variables that are actually specific to the module, such as:

  - The `module` and `exports` objects that the implementor can use to export values from the module.
  - The convenience variables `__filename` and `__dirname`, containing the module's absolute filename and directory path.